# How to get raw touchscreen data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touchscreen

I know I can get touch events in my iPhone app. But these touch events are filtered for me. If I press the device against my face, it filters out these touch events because it can detect its not a finger.

How would I get the raw touch events, not filtered in any way?

Comment: You touch your face against the device? What kind of app are you writing?

Comment: competition for iHarmonica? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no public API for this. The closest you can get is GSEvent, from the GraphicsServices private framework.