# iphone touch shape or raw data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Anyone know if it is yet possible to detect the touch shape?  Maybe through getting the raw touchscreen data?

I found this question/answer here: [How to get raw touchscreen data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789737/iphone-raw-touchscreen-data)

That mentions GSEvent, but it is quite old.

I'd like to try to get a rough calculation of the pressure of the touch by its shape/area, but of course UITouch only gives a calculated point.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, raw touch data is contained in the `GSEventRecord` object, particularly what you are looking for is the `pathMajorRadius` property on `GSPathInfo`, which gives the major radious on the tap. This is a rough estimate of the pressure, but take into account big/small fingers give also different measures.

Watch out for the `pathPressure` property also in `GSPathInfo`, it does NOT contain the pressure. It always contains 1, capacitive screens (like the iPad's or IPhone's) do not measure pressure at all.

If you are planning submitting your app in the app store, you won't be able to do it if you include access to private frameworks (like in this case, `GSEvent.h` in the `GraphicServices` framework). But what you need to do is catch every `UIEvent` in the `sendEvent` method of your subclassed `UIApplication`, then use the methods in
https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h
to get the information of the GSEvent.

Comment: "does NOT contain the pressure" - how does GarageBand work then?

Comment: There are a number of ways to calculate pressure, or better said, approximate. One is the accelerometer values on different tap moments or "long taps" for example (which is "legal"). Another is the radious of the tap, which is with private frameworks and therefore "illegal". But you can be sure, if GarageBand used private APIs, it would not be accepted in the apple store.

Comment: Lol, why would Apple not admit its own app to the AppStore even if it uses 'private' frameworks?

Comment: Well, I guess they're allowed to do it

Comment: Cool, I'll have to give this a try some time.

Comment: About the GarageBand app, I recall from their first demo that they use the accelerometer to detect tap strength, not blob size.  But blob size would be useful for other things, such as simulating a crescendo.